# GROUP BY ultimo registro

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estou fazendo uma consulta no banco, segue minha tabela abaixo

```
id | protocolo | status | alteracao | datahora
1        2         1        teste     2014-11-10 15:23:44
2        2         3        teste     2014-11-10 14:23:44
3        2         4        teste     2014-11-10 13:23:44
4        1         2        teste     2014-11-10 09:23:44
5        1         3        teste     2014-11-10 10:23:44
```

preciso trazer o resultado agrupando os protocolos pelo ultimovalor da `datahora`,

ou seja preciso do resultado assim:

```
id | protocolo | status | alteracao | datahora
1        2         1        teste     2014-11-10 15:23:44
5        1         3        teste     2014-11-10 10:23:44
```

Comment: Não entendi @Furlan, consegue editar sua pergunta demostrando como você quer a consulta?

Comment: opa @ThiagoThaison so um momento

Comment: @ThiagoThaison alterei minha questao e deixei como ela tem que me retornar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você poderá utilizar a seguinte query:

```
select * from tabela t where t.id = (select id from tabela where protocolo = t.protocolo order by datahora desc limit 0, 1);
```

Dessa maneira, o resultado será como o demonstrado na pergunta.

Comment: sua resposta me ajudou muito, precisei dela, pq ela me mostrou oq eu queria mesmo sem me adaptar a nada valew.

Comment: Sim @Furlan, concordo, após ver o levantamento feito por Thiago, vi que minha resposta até ajudaria se os outros valores não tivesse que ser do mesmo registro. A resposta que responde essa pergunta completamente é está. +1

Answer (score 5):

É só utilizar os operadores MAX e MIN;

```sql
SELECT min( t.id ),
       t.protocolo,
       min( t.status ),
       min( t.alteracao ),
       max( t.datahora )
  FROM tabela AS t
 GROUP BY t.protocolo;
```

Algo similar a isso no MYSQL.

[Exemplo de MAX e MIN em MySql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48203/how-to-get-max-and-min-in-group-by-query).

> Obs: não tenho mysql aqui para testar, então pode haver algum erro de sintaxe. Se houver, me avisem que corrijo.

Comment: valew @fernando vc salvou o dia!

Comment: Legal @Furlan que ajudou, só postei sem referencias pois estou na correria, a noite dou uma melhorada na resposta e testo no mysql. hehe

Comment: Posso estar errado, mas parece que esta query retornou os menores valores de cada coluna, e não os registros com a maior data de cada protocolo.

Comment: A sim @ThiagoThaison, acho que você esta correto, mais não sei se isso é um problema para ele. Mais o que você citou é verdade.

Comment: valew @Fernando obrigado mesmo pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

No MySQL basta voce ordenar o seu SELECT do mais recente para o mais antigo e aplicar o GROUP BY. Ele vai retornar a primeira linha para cada agrupamento.

```
SELECT id, protocolo, status, alteracao, datahora
FROM tabela
ORDER BY id, protocolo, status, datahora DESC
GROUP BY protocolo
```

Importante esclarecer que isso nao funciona em todos os bancos de dados. Por exemplo, no Oracle ele nao permite que voce faça `SELECT` de colunas que nao estao no GROUP BY, ai voce teria que usar `WINDOW FUNCTIONS`, mas no MySQL isso é possivel.

Comment: ainda ta me retornando mais de um resultado com o mesmo protocolo

Comment: @Furlan Editei minha resposta. Na verdade o agrupamento tem que ser so pelo protocolo.