# relacionar duas tabelas listando somente ultimo registro php

Tags: php, mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Eu tenho uma tabela gabarito da seguinte forma:

```
|  materia  | provaID | matricula | questao | resposta |
 matematica    303      211834      quest1      A    
 matematica    303      211834      quest2      C    
 matematica    303      211834      quest3      B    
 matematica    303      211834      quest4      D   
 matematica    304      211834      quest1      C   
 matematica    304      211834      quest2      A    
 matematica    303      741431      quest1      B   
 matematica    303      741431      quest2      D   
 matematica    303      741431      quest3      C   
 matematica    303      741431      quest4      E
```

A tabela "prova" está assim:

```
|  id  |  materia  |
  303    matematica
  304    matematica
```

O que eu preciso é relacionar as duas tabelas, mas listar somente as "respostas" da ultima "prova" porém de cada matricula ficando assim:

```
                    |  materia  | provaID | matricula | questao | resposta |

**Ultimo desse aluno** matematica    304      211834      quest1      C   
**Ultimo desse aluno** matematica    304      211834      quest2      A

**Ultimo desse aluno** matematica    303      741431      quest1      B   
**Ultimo desse aluno** matematica    303      741431      quest2      D   
**Ultimo desse aluno** matematica    303      741431      quest3      C   
**Ultimo desse aluno** matematica    303      741431      quest4      E
```

Esse post [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175280/como-montar-um-select-para-retornar-a-ultima-altera%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-status-de-cada-id](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175280/como-montar-um-select-para-retornar-a-ultima-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-status-de-cada-id) não me ajudou pois ele retorna UMA linha de cada ID, eu preciso que ele retorne todas as ULTIMAS linhas de cada matricula, ficando da forma acima.

Vejam, esse codigo me retorna parte do que eu preciso:

```
    $gabaritoByAluno = $db->prepare("SELECT gabarito.*, prova.* FROM gabarito INNER JOIN prova ON (gabarito.provaID != prova.id) WHERE gabarito.materia = ? AND gabarito.matricula = ?");
$gabaritoByAluno->execute(array("AUTORIDADE ESPIRITUAL", "218113"));

 while ($dadosByAlunos = $gabaritoByAluno->fetch()) {
     echo $dadosByAlunos['questao'] . '<br>';
 }
```

ele me retorna todas as questoes, eu quero que retorne somente as ultimas questoes que foram quest1 e quest2 do provaID 304

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Dividindo o problema em partes

Com essa *query* obtemos o maior `provaID` de cada `matricula`:

```sql
SELECT matricula, MAX(provaID) AS prova
FROM gabarito
GROUP BY matricula
```

O `GROUP BY` faz com que seja retornada apenas uma linha para cada matrícula, e o `MAX` obtem o maior `provaID` de cada matrícula individualmente.

### Obtendo as questões de cada prova

Para obter as questões das provas retornadas com a *query* acima, basta um `LEFT JOIN` dos resultados obtidos, com a própria tabela gabaritos:

```sql
SELECT   gabarito.materia,
         gabarito.provaID,
         gabarito.matricula,
         gabarito.questao,
         gabarito.resposta

FROM  ( SELECT   matricula, MAX(provaID) AS prova
        FROM     gabarito
        GROUP BY matricula
      ) AS ultima
      LEFT JOIN gabarito
        ON  ultima.prova     = gabarito.provaID
        AND ultima.matricula = gabarito.matricula

ORDER BY matricula, questao
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8aa81/2)**.

Para quem não conhece, a *query* usada entre parênteses no lugar do nome de outra tabela é conhecida como *subquery*. Quando a *subquery* se comporta como se fosse uma tabela real, é mais especificamente conhecida como "Tabela derivada".

Em outras palavras, isto...:

```sql
FROM  ( SELECT   matricula, MAX(provaID) AS prova
        FROM     gabarito
        GROUP BY matricula
      ) AS ultima
      LEFT JOIN gabarito
```

...comporta-se como se existisse realmente uma tabela chamada `ultima` com as últimas provas de cada um, e tivéssemos feito simplesmente:

```sql
FROM  ultima
      LEFT JOIN gabarito
```

Leituras recomendadas:

> [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70)

> [Como montar um SELECT para retornar a ultima alteração de status de cada id?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175280/70)

> [GROUP BY ultimo registro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39942/70)